# Find the exchange name through which message has been consumed

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a code which has both consumer and producer. I want to differentiate or find the exact exchange name through which the consumer has consumed the message. For example, I have almost 5 exchanges and I want to know through which exchange out of that 5 the consumer has received it's message. How can this be achieved?

I have done lot of homework but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Messages are consumed from queues, not exchanges.

The way to figure out original exchange that message was published to is to use [Firehose Tracer plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) (maybe even with [rabbitmq-tracing
 plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tracing) alongside).

Alternatively, you may figure out original exchange by comparing queues bindings with message routing key. This usually work well in most cases, unless you have really wired publishers and routing logic.

P.S.: finally, if you have at least read access to publishers code you can figure out where each messages goes from.